# How do I know which request belongs to what partial data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the node.js server below. Suppose that multiple clients make a POST request. But these will share the same variable body and the final string will become meaningless. Is is possible to identify a request by id or something? All I have is request.headers, but that does not contain any unique information.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();

server.on("request", onRequest);
server.listen(8001, "127.0.0.1");

function onRequest(request, response) // assuming "POST"
{
    var body = "";

    request.on("data", function (data) { body = body + data; });
    request.on("end", function () { console.log(body); });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; the requests are parceled out and you're attaching a function to the events for that particular request.

Comment: Maybe I get it, each new requests calls function onRequest and creates therefore its own body variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in general inherit scopes (from their parents), so each `body` variable will be correctly concatenated for each request.